# Why are these specific stress invariants chosen?

Tags: tensor-calculus, stress-strain

I've seen these invariants of the Cauchy stress tensor $S$ defined in multiple places:

$$J_1 =  \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3 = Tr(S)$$
$$J_2 =  \lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2$$
$$J_3 = \lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3 = \det{S}$$

where $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues of the stress tensor. But I suppose we could use almost any three functions of the eigenvalues. Is there any specific reason to choose these, other than the fact that they can be calculated without first finding the eigenvalues?

Comment: Are you sure on the second one? I supposed it was $\lambda_1\lambda_2+ \lambda_1\lambda_3 + \lambda_2\lambda_3$.

Comment: My text book claims $J_2 = \lambda_1\lambda_1+\lambda_2\lambda_2+\lambda_3\lambda_3 = (J_1^2 - Tr(S^2))/2$, which doesn't check out since $ (J_1^2 - Tr(S^2))/2$ is what you say. Probably a typo in the book. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the characteristic polynomial: $$P(\lambda)= \det(\lambda I - S)$$
**and the right-hand side does depend on the particular orthonormal reference frame you fix to compute the stress tensor**, you see that:
$$P(\lambda) = \lambda^3 - J_1 \lambda^2 -J'_2 \lambda -J_3$$
where $$J'_2 = -(\lambda_1\lambda_2 + \lambda_1 \lambda_3 + \lambda_2\lambda_3 )\:.$$
However: $$J_1^2 = J_2 -2J_2'$$
so the triple $J_1,J_2,J_3$ and the triple $J_1,J'_2,J_3$ include  same information.

The scalars $J_i$ are "**invariant**" (also said "objective"), in the sense that they depend on the tensor only, and not on the particular representation of the tensor you use, i.e., its matrix form in a reference (orthonormal) frame. This is because $P(\lambda)$ does depend on that choice. Indeed, changing reference frame the matrix $S$ representing the tensor changes as $S\to S'= RSR^t$, where $R\in O(3)$ is the rotation matrix relating the considered pair of frames. Next:
$$\det( \lambda I -RSR^t)= \det( \lambda RIR^t -RSR^t)= \det(R(\lambda I- S)R^t)= \det(R)\det(R^t)  \det(\lambda I -S) = (\det R)^2  \det(\lambda I -S) =
 \det(\lambda I -S) $$
because $R\in O(3)$ entails $\det R=\pm1$.

Comment: @Anna : The main interest is that the quantities $J_1,J_2,J'_2,J_3$ are invariant by a permutation on the roots $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\lambda_3$, so the above quantities are symmetric invariants of the roots.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Wikipedia page on invariants of tensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariants_of_tensors), the reason for this particular choice of three functions of the eigenvalues (instead of any other arbitrary three functions) is stated in the section "Engineering Application". To cite the sentence which answers your question:

> A scalar valued tensor function $f$ that depends merely on the three invariants of a symmetric 3×3 tensor $\mathbf{A}$ is objective, i.e., independent from rotations of the coordinate system. Moreover, every objective tensor function depends only on the tensor's invariants. Thus, objectivity of a tensor function is fulfilled if, and only if, for some function $g:R^3\to R$ we have $f(\mathbf{A})=g(I_A,II_A,III_A).$

Unfortunately a proof isn't given, and the only reference is to J. A. Spencer's Continuum Mechanics, which I don't have a copy of. However, it appears that the reason this particular choice of three functions of the three eigenvalues is used (rather than some other arbitrary choice) has to do with the fact that any frame-invariant function of a tensor can be computed with the invariants alone, ie, you don't actually need to know the tensor input, you just need to know the invariants.

If someone has a better knowledge of this isomorphism, by all means feel free to tack on more info, as I'm not an expert. Also, I have a hunch this is intimately tied in to the [Rivlin-Erickson theorem](http://people.ricam.oeaw.ac.at/m.sini/Chapter-V.pdf).